# ui-sref not rendering correctly

Tags: angularjs

```
  .state('app.post', {
    url: "/post/:postId",
    views: {
      'menuContent' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/viewPost.html',
        controller: 'ViewPostController'  
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.post.edit', {
    url: "/edit/:postId",
    views: {
      'menuContent@app' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/editPost.html',
        controller: 'EditPostController'  
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.post.comments', {
    url: "/comments/:postId",
    views: {
      'menuContent@app' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/post-comments.html',
        controller: 'PostCommentsController'  
      }
    }
  })
```

I have this

```
<a class="tab-item" ui-sref="app.post.comments({postId:'{{post.id}}'})">
  <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i>
  Comment
</a>
```

it rendering like:

```
<a class="tab-item" ui-sref="app.post.comments({postId:'306cc780-71db-11e5-b49b-7bdc2a9aa3c7'})" href="#/app/post//comments/">
      <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i>
      Comment
    </a>
```

post is missing in href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioning `postId` inside the url in `app.post` is enough like `url: "/post/:postId",`, In `app.post.edit` & `app.post.comments` should only have `url`s like  `/edit` & `/comments`.

So that while passing `postId` it only get merged with the parent post.

Then your ui-sref should not have interpolation

```
ui-sref="app.post.comments({postId: post.id})"
```

Will be rendered as

```
href="#/app/post/306cc780-71db-11e5-b49b-7bdc2a9aa3c7/comments"
```

**States**

```
.state('app.post', {
    url: "/post/:postId",
    views: {
      'menuContent' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/viewPost.html',
        controller: 'ViewPostController'  
      }
    }
})

.state('app.post.edit', {
    url: "/edit",
    views: {
      'menuContent@app' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/editPost.html',
        controller: 'EditPostController'  
      }
    }
})
.state('app.post.comments', {
    url: "/comments",
    views: {
      'menuContent@app' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/post-comments.html',
        controller: 'PostCommentsController'  
      }
    }
})
```